# For every row of a dataframe, loop over a list of names

Tags: python, loops

I may have bit off more than I could chew at work... But theres no going back for me now...

So I have two tables:
Table 1: Tasks need to be assigned & list of eligible agents

| tasks | names |
| --- | --- |
| taskA | [susan, mike, bob, ann] |
| taskB | [susan, david, pat] |
| ...... |  |

Table 2: Workload of each agent

| name | assigned_task_count |
| --- | --- |
| bob | 3 |
| ann | 2 |
| susan | 6 |
| ...... |  |

For each unassigned task, I want to loop over the qualified agents that can take on this task, find the agent with the least task count, then assign this task to them. This should update Table 2 with +1 on their 'assigned_task_count'.

I'm not trained in Python, only learned on the job. So my foundations are pretty weak.. (and it's come to bite me in the ass..) Please help me save my job...

**!!! Editing my question for clarity !!!**

Ultimately, I want two tables. One that documents the task and assigned agent && one that tells me the new task per rep.

Comment: Do you need to do this all at once, meaning assign all the jobs, or do you need to get the updated DataFrame after each job is assigned?

Comment: After Task 1 is assigned, Table 2 needs to update (+1 for whoever's been assigned), then move on the next Task, search the new Table 2 to see who is the qualified agent with least work

Comment: well yeah I mean do you want a function that does this one step or a function that goes through the whole table 1

Comment: oh whole table please!!!! much appreciated!!:)

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'tasks':['a', 'b'], 'names':[['susan', 'mike', 'bob', 'ann'], ['susan', 'david', 'pat']]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['bob', 'ann', 'susan'], 'assigned_task_count':[3,2,6]})

def assign_task(df1, df2):
    df1 = df1.copy()
    assigned_to = []
    df2 = df2.set_index('name')
    for name in df1['names']:
        qualified_agents = df2.index[df2.index.isin(name)]
        agent = qualified_agents[df2.loc[qualified_agents, 'assigned_task_count'].argmin()]
        df2.loc[agent] += 1
        assigned_to.append(agent)
    df2 = df2.reset_index()
    df1['assigned_to'] = assigned_to
    return df1, df2
```

Comment: I got this error: IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: are you running the above code or on your data?

Comment: I tried with your above code!

Comment: I ran the above code with `assign_task(df1, df2)` and did not show any error. I am using Python 3.8 and Pandas 1.1.4

Comment: I was using Py2, no error in Py3! but how do I return a table with Task and Assigned Agent?

Comment: see the updated code